# Designing Graphics For .NET Apps Resolution

Tags: adobe-fireworks, ppi, resolution

What resolution (in pixels/inch) should I use when designing graphics for a standard Windows Forms .NET application?

I am using Adobe Creative Suites to design the graphics.  I will be using the System.Drawing.Graphics class in .NET to draw the graphics on the screen.

Comment: Let me know if this is a coding question that needs to be moved to stackoverflow.com.  I was split on which site it should go on.

Comment: This isn't a coding question, it's a design question. It's on topic on this site. The platform or framework doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The programming framework you are using has no bearing on the resolution of images you are using.

For on screen graphics, resolution in the context of pixels/inch is determined by the device itself. All you need to do is make the image the pixel size you want it to be.

In other words, if you want an image 100px x 100px, set up your photoshop file to be 100px x 100px. The PPI setting is irrelevant.

Comment: Side note: If you are making an scalable app, start from the biggest resolution you will allow.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for.